# Is using useState Hook while using redux to handle input forms an anti pattern?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm not able to grasp this point, If the store is a place where the entire application's state resides, why am I using useState hook to create a local state for my form components? Ideally, I should be mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps for handling inputs too? Is it an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 2):

The creator of Redux, Dan Abramov, has commented on this earlier. Basically, it depends, and usually if the state is local to the application, then keep it there. This is stuff such as the state of a toggled button, if something has been pressed, etc.

Global app state is usually best left to your Redux store.

Dispatching all changes to redux for everything will needlessly invoke lots of updates on the connected components for nothing.

Regarding this:

> the store is a place where the entire application's state resides

Where is that "fact" from? While Dan might have promoted this view early on, it is years since he changed his view on this. Basically the current view is to be a bit pragmatic, both in regards to what state to put in Redux stores and the whole split between [presentational and container components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Comment: I understand the goal here is to be pragmatic, I took the basic example a bit seriously.

Comment: @Yashwanthsomayajula Definitely not the first to do so. I was in that camp as well at one time :-) Putting internal state in Redux can make sense, mind you, for instance if you want to handle exiting a form and then keeping the state until the user visits it again to continue a draft.